# GraphQL and SQL - Is It Possible to Reduce Database Calls with 1 SQL JOIN?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, graphql

I have a question...

So I've been looking around, and it seems that GraphQL just cannot optimize its resolvers and "combine" them into one SQL query with multiple joins.

For example, let's say we have this imaginary relationship:

```
user(id=2) {
  name
  companies {
    name
    country {
      id
      name
      planet {
       id
       name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know, you could fetch all this data in one sql query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN companies ON users.id = companies.id 
INNER JOIN countries ON countries.id = companies.country_id 
INNER JOIN planets ON planets.id = countries.planet_id 
WHERE users.id = 2;
```

It doesn't seem to be possible with GraphQL. At most, you can use a data-loader, which allows me to have 4 queries:

1. Get users by id 2
2. Get companies where user_id = 2
3. Get countries with country_ids from Query (2)
4. Get planets with planet_ids from Query (3)

Am I understanding it right?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can using a few different approaches. Serving a GraphQL API doesn’t mean you have to use resolvers and the data loader approach for implementation necessarily.

You can use CTEs like postgraphile (https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/)  and actually write resolvers to create a single sql query. But with customised resolver behaviour so that you don’t actually run the query until the entire query is assembled.

We take a different approach for the Hasura GraphQL engine (https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine) , and skip writing resolvers and write the GraphQL web server as a “compiler” instead that compiles GraphQL to SQL.